# How to show the action confirmation window?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

Good afternoon.

On the view there is a link Delete

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete">Delete</a>
```

when you click on which you want to show a dialog

- with the text "Are you sure?"
- Yes and No buttons
- if we press No, then nothing happens (the dialog closes)
- if we click Yes, then we call the method in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in its simplest terms, you can use the `Javascript` confirmation alert box:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteOperation();">Delete</a>
```

Corresponding `Javascript` usin `AJAX` to post your data to the `Controller`:

```
function DeleteOperation() {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")) {
        //Get your id from the element where it is defined
        var idToDelete = $("#id").val();
        var json = { idToDelete: idToDelete};

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
            success: function (data) {
                  if(data.status=="true")
                  {
                    alert(data.msg);
                    location.reload();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    alert(data.msg);
                  }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error in deleting the entry. Please contact admin.");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

And your `Controller` method would look like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

        //Get your variables here from AJAX call
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(jsondata["idToDelete"]);
        //Can be webservice call or DB call
        var deleteoperationresult = DeleteOperation(id);
        if(deleteoperationresult)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "true", msg = "Successfully deleted" }); 
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { status = "false", msg = "Could not delete the entry!" });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { status = "false", msg = ex.Message});
    }
}
```